# jQuery on change always prints same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the output when I print a collection variable in console log.

```
(14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {px_id: 2713, attr_name: "A", other_id: 4}
1: {px_id: 2712, attr_name: "B", other_id: 4}
2: {px_id: 2698, attr_name: "C", other_id: 4}
3: {px_id: 2694, attr_name: "D", other_id: 4}
4: {px_id: 2695, attr_name: "E", other_id: 4}
5: {px_id: 2693, attr_name: "F", other_id: 4}
6: {px_id: 2697, attr_name: "G", other_id: 4}
7: {px_id: 2714, attr_name: "H", other_id: 4}
8: {px_id: 2711, attr_name: "I", other_id: 4}
9: {px_id: 2699, attr_name: "J", other_id: 4}
10: {px_id: 2696, attr_name: "K", other_id: 4}
11: {px_id: 2710, attr_name: "L", other_id: 4}
12: {px_id: 2709, attr_name: "M", other_id: 4}
13: {px_id: 2708, attr_name: "N", other_id: 4}
length: 14__proto__: Array(0)
```

And in the HTML, this is how the select option is getting populated :

```
var html = "";
$_.each(collection, function(index_, term_) {
            html += "<option value='" + term_.px_id + "'>" + term_.attr_name + "</option>";
 });
 $_(".attrList").html(html);
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<table class="enc-data-table" align="center">

      <tr>
          <th><b>Attributes</b></th>
             <td> <select id="attrList"  class="attrList"></select></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

In the console log, I can see `2713` getting displayed with the help of the following javascript function.

```
  $(".attrList").on("change", function() {
                            var testVal = $(".attrList option:selected").val();
                            console.log(testVal);
                            //alert(testVal);
                        });
```

When I select different `attr_name` from the dropdown menu, the `console.log(testVal);` and  `alert(testVal);` always display the number  `2713`. When I select `B`, I was expecting console log to display `2712`, 
but it again displayed `2713`. for `C`, I was expecting it to be `2698` but again  I got `2713` etc. What am I doing wrong above?

Just for testing, I changed this line   `var testVal = $(".attrList option:selected").val();` to `var testVal = $(".attrList option:selected").text();` and I was able to see A, B or C etc based on the 
selection but there seem to be something wrong with the value part.

I did a simple test here and it works fine :

```js
$(".attrList").on("change", function() {
  var testVal = $(".attrList option:selected").val();
  console.log(testVal);
  alert(testVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="attribute_config_dialog" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close close-icon" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h2 class="modal-title">Test</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <table class="enc-data-table" align="center">

          <tr class="spaceUnder">
            <th><b>Attributes</b></th>
            <td>
              <select id="attrList" class="attrList">
                <option selected value="DEFAULT">Default</option>
                <option value="SEL1">Selection 1</option>
                <option value="SEL2">Selection 2</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>



        </table>

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah right... It's strange. It works totally fine here...

Comment: The Javascript code snippet that I posted above works fine for me as well. But the information with which I am dealing with (`collection` variable), I am facing problem with retrieving new value based on on change event. I even tested like this `var html = "";
                    html += "<option value='test'></option>"; ` but in this scenario, it always print `test` in the console log.

Comment: If it works fine here, but not in your project, then the problem is with some part of your project not shown here.    The first thing I'd check is whatever's filling that `collection` variable: make sure it contains what you expect when you're trying to use it.  (Is it async?  If so, are you waiting for that async call to complete before trying to use that data?)

Comment: Why `$(".attrList option:selected").val()` and not just `$(".attrList").val()`? Or better yet, `$(this).val()`?  Are there multiple selects with the class `attrList` on the same page? If so, your selector will *always reference the first one*, regardless of which one you're changing.

Comment: @TylerRoper No, there is no multiple selectors based requirement. User will be selecting one at a time.

Comment: @Coder Not asking about how many they'll select, I'm talking about *anything* marked with a class of `.attrList`. Do you use `class="attrList"` *more than once* on your page?

Comment: @TylerRoper Awesome. It worked with `$(this).val()`. Could you explain why it was getting stuck with first one? Also, this didn't happen when I used `.text()` method instead of `.val()`.  And I don't use the class more than once in my page.

Comment: And in the above snippet also it works fine with `$(".attrList option:selected").val();`.

Comment: @Coder Without seeing the issue replicated, it's difficult to figure out where it's coming from. If you do an "Inspect Element" and CTRL+F for `attrList`, you're *sure* there are no others? That's the only way I've been able to replicate the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172179/discussion-between-coder-and-tyler-roper).